# Citation of Mission Planner

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I been using mission planner for some aerial survey study (as my ground control station and autonomous mission planner). However, I haven't been able to find all the information to properly cite this software.

1. Mission Planer; Computer Software; ArduPilot Development Team: "City, Country", 2012.

Comment: You should cite it just like any other mobile app. For instance, if you are using APA format you can use this template: https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/03/how-to-cite-a-mobile-app.html

Comment: But mission planner it is not a mobile app.

Comment: I understand how that argument can be made, but this is the convention in the literature based on my experience. Michael Osborne, who created the software, also makes this recommendation in this thread from 2015 : https://discuss.ardupilot.org/t/reference-citation-for-mission-planner/4950

Comment: Do you happen to know a paper in in which the author(s) cite mission planner?

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=15058731290445770119&as_sdt=5,44&sciodt=0,44&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the follow specifically for Mission Planner following the 6th edition of the APA Style Guide. Adjust the date/version as appropriate.

Oborne, Michael (2019). Mission Planner (Version 1.3.70) [Computer software]. Retrieved from https://ardupilot.org/planner/

If you just want to cite open source software from a specific team you could use:

Mission Planner. (2019). ArduPilot Development Team (Version 1.3.70) [Computer software]. Retrieved from https://ardupilot.org/planner/

Answer (score 2):

Here is the google link to the most used format: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15058731290445770119&hl=en&as_sdt=5,44&sciodt=0,44

And the second most used: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1059444725289657290&hl=en&as_sdt=5,44&sciodt=0,44